# Force desktop version of websites?

Tags: browser

Chrome has a feature that requests the desktop version of sites, but some websites don't oblige, and continue giving the mobile version.

Is there any way to force them to give the desktop version? I'm open to using any Android version, any browser, root permissions and Xposed Framework.

Comment: It would help if you give links for some websites which are not following your command.

Comment: @Firelord I will post it here the next time it happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites redirect a mobile device to a specific mobile site. These are usually prefixed with the m. or mobile. subdomain (e.g. m.foo.com).
If you get a desktop version of one of those sites, you'll still get the mobile version because that's all they can give you.
So make sure you switch the flag before going to the site and see if that works.